# problem with linked libraries or classes?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios-simulator

i recently finished one project..now when i create a new navigation project in xcode and try to run it in simulator the application crashes and  error in debugger window shows that i am missing some classes which i had used in my previous project(not in this one) and in some cases it gives

> Couldn't register com.yourcompany.GuessGame with the bootstrap server. Error: unknown error code.
>   This generally means that another instance of this process was already running or is hung in the debugger.

is this some problem related to linked libraries??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you're tried restarting the simulator / restarting XCode / cleaning your build (build->Clean All Targets) ?

What's the name of your first project beacuse if it's com.yourcomany.GuessGame as well, you might run into problems?